# How can I parse Delivered-To headers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, parsing

I am trying to parse an email in Ruby on Rails that is an attachment?  I am not to worried about the regular expression, but more so the method I use to get the parsed output.  I am looking to do this without any mail parsing gems.  The code below appears to work, is this the correct way?

model.rb

```
def parse_delivered_to
  str = File.read("public/emails/email.txt").to_s
  delivered_to = str.match(/(Delivered-To: )[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.+[a-z]+[a-z]+[a-z]/i)
end
```

show.html.erb

```
<%= @email.parse_delivered_to %><br>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Analysis

The email specifications allow for [multiline headers](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#section-2.2.3), which your current expression won't match. In addition, I don't think your regular expression allows for all of the permissible address characters.

#### Solution

Using a variation of procmail's `^TO_` syntax should allow you to match multiline address patterns more liberally. For example:

```
header.scan( /^Delivered-To:(.*[^-a-zA-Z0-9_.])?/im ).flatten.map(&:strip)
```

#### Some Tests and Examples

```
header = "Delivered-To:\n  Foo <foo@example.com>"
header.scan( /^Delivered-To:(.*[^-a-zA-Z0-9_.])?/im ).flatten.map(&:strip)
header.scan( /^Delivered-To:(.*[^-a-zA-Z0-9_.])?/im ).flatten.map(&:strip)
=> ["Foo <foo@example.com>"]

header.scan( /^Delivered-To:(.*[^-a-zA-Z0-9_.])?/im).
 flatten.map(&:strip).to_s.scan(/[\w@.+_-]+/).grep(/@/).first.to_s
=> "foo@example.com"

'Delivered-To: foo.bar+extension@example.com'.
  scan( /^Delivered-To:(.*[^-a-zA-Z0-9_.])?/im).
  flatten.map(&:strip).to_s.scan(/[\w.+_-]+/)
=> ["foo.bar+extension"]

'Delivered-To: foo.bar-extension@example.com'.
  scan( /^Delivered-To:(.*[^-a-zA-Z0-9_.])?/im).
  flatten.map(&:strip).to_s.scan(/[\w.+_-]+/)
=> ["foo.bar-extension"]
```